# How to run a command at one stage and use the result for another?

Tags: docker

My application as:

```
myapp
├── Dockerfile
├── main.go
├── swagger
│   ├── definitions
│   │   └── index.yaml
│   ├── info
│   │   └── index.yaml
│   ├── paths
│   │   └── index.yaml
│   └── index.yaml
...
```

I want to run a convert command first to make file from `swagger/index.yaml` to `swagger/index.json`. `multi-file-swagger` can do it.

In my `Dockerfile`, I did:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install multi-file-swagger -g
COPY swagger .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/swagger
CMD [ "multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json" ]

FROM golang:1.12
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app swagger
CMD ["app"]
```

But after build and run the app, check the path in the container, didn't find `index.json` under `swagger` folder.

Comment: The `CMD` in the first stage will only run if you pull the built image ID out of the `docker build` output and explicitly `docker run` that image (at which point it will fail because the JSON form of `CMD`/`RUN` doesn't understand shell redirection at all).  It doesn't run in a multi-stage build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
RUN npm install multi-file-swagger -g
ADD swagger /usr/src/app/swagger
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/swagger
RUN multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json

FROM golang:1.12
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/swagger swagger
CMD ["app"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change `CMD [ "multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json" ]` to `RUN multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json` in order for multi-file-swagger to be run during the build of the builder container, so that the result is available during the build of the app container.

Comment: I have tried that, but got `The command '/bin/sh -c multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json' returned a non-zero code: 1` error.

Comment: Perhaps try removing `> index.json` temporarily to see what multi-file-swagger is doing. If it's working successfully you'd see a load of JSON appear during the build, but if it fails for some reason it may print out the error message to indicate what the problem is.